# Change header HTTP Server [SharePoint Online]

Tags: http, http-headers, sharepoint-online

We would like to know if it's possible to change/hide the header HTTP server showed by SharePoint Online.
More precisely : "X-Powered-By" and "X-AspNet-Version"
We want to hide for exemple the http response : "Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5" or used code "X-Powered-By:ASP.NET" or "X-AspNet-Version:4.0.30319"

thanks for your help.
Regards

Comment: The obvious question is, Why?

Comment: As you are "renting" SharePoint Online and do not own the servers or software, it's generally not possible to change something like this.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. The case is security audit ask to us to hide this information. We will say it's no possible.